# button onclick update in database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp

when i click on yes button, the approve column in database has to be updated to 1 and when clicked no it has to be updated to 0.Its default value in db is -1.i have wriiten the script which calls a ajax function to update thefield as 1 or 0 depending on button click.The script is as below.

```
    <input type="button" onClick="save(this);" id="btnyes" value="Yes"> <input type="button" id="btnno" onClick="save(this);" value="No">
       <img id="yes" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
        <img id="no" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
     <?php }
     else if ($tdata['approve']=='1')
     { ?>
     <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
     <?php }
     else 
     { ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/red.png"  alt="">
     <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    endforeach;  
    ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          var url="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'ajax','action'=>'getapproveinfo')); ?>";
      function save(obj){
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data: {status: this.value},
success: function(data) {
if(obj.value='yes'){
document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
}
else if{
document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'block';
}
alert("Ajax save executed!");
}
}
 });
 }
    </script>
```

And my ajax function for updating the field is below.

```
  public function approveinfo($approve="") {
    if(!empty($approve ) && ($approve=='yes')  {            
    $this->Purchaseorder->updateAll(array('Purchaseorder.approve' =>"1"),
        array('Purchaseorder.id' =>$id));
        $result=array();
        array_push($result,$info);
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Now when i click on yes or no button, no action happens.What is the error?

Comment: where is url field  in ajax, u have to define url in your ajax as you have defined data,type, etc..

Comment: yes, u have to, other wise how ajax'll know the url to hit

Comment: Yes, but pls print it to check your url first

Comment: $.ajax({
url:url
type: "POST",
data: {status: this.value},

Comment: print yr url and tell me full url, have u sent request through postman or equivalent