# ajax update in database cakephp

Tags: ajax, cakephp

```
<script>
  function save(obj){
 var res = obj.id.split("-");
   $.ajax({
var url="<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'ajax','action'=>'approveinfo')); ?>";
type: "POST",
data: {status: this.value},
success: function(data) {
 if(obj.id=='btnyes-'+res[1]){
 var yesid='btnyes'+res[1];
document.getElementById('btnyes-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes-'+res[1]).style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('no-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
} 
else if(obj.id=='btnno-'+res[1]) {
document.getElementById('btnyes-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes-'+res[1]).style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('no-'+res[1]).style.display = 'block';
  }
alert("Ajax save executed!");
}
}
 });
 }
```

this script should call ajax function and update the value as 1 or 0
based on onclick function.
But it doesnt update..what is the error?
Ajax code is below

```
        public function approveinfo($approve="") {
          if(!empty($approve))  && ($approve=='yes')  {         

        $this->Purchaseorder->updateAll(array('Purchaseorder.approve' =>"1"),
        else{
        $this->Purchaseorder->updateAll(array('Purchaseorder.approve' =>"0"),
        }

        $result=array();
        array_push($result,$info);
        echo json_encode($result);
        exit;
       }
       }
```

What should i do so that the value getsupdated as 1 when i click on yes and 0 when i click on no

Comment: it seems that you always call the url `ajax/approveinfo` without passing any value to the function. Maybe you are passing the value via POST, but nowhere in your controller you check POST data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [button onclick update in database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304471/button-onclick-update-in-database)

Answer (score 0):

Like arilia said, your are passing the values via POST to your controllers action. All you need to do is, check the post values:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){

   if(!empty($this->request->data['status']))  && ($this->request->data['status']=='yes'){  

   }
}
```